# Open file using commandline

Tags: c, file, codelite

I'm working on an assignment and I have to open a file from command line upon executing the program.

Example:

```
program.exe file.txt
```

However that is not working at all for me. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? This is the first time I'm working with taking a file as a parameter.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int value;
    value = fileRead(argv[1]);
}

int fileRead(char argv[]) {
  int value;

  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  if (fp) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d",  &value);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file!\n");
  }
  return value;
}
```

Comment: `argv[1]` shouldn't be in quotes.

Comment: @JosephSible I removed the quotes and now I received many warnings. "passing argument 1 of 'fopen' makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: Can you post your whole program's code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/507/files-and-i-o-streams#t=201703110256403462166

Comment: @JosephSible Added program coce in main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up a character and a string. You pass `argv[1]` to `fileRead` as `argv`. Then in `fileRead`, you do `argv[1]` again. This effectively does `argv[1][1]`, which just gives the second character of the string. You need to either remove the `[1]` from in `main` and then change the argument type, or remove the `[1]` from `fileRead`.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem and I understand now. Very helpful :)